# Per-Request static data in Signalr

Tags: .net, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to statically store user information for the lifetime of a SignalR request. I have done so in WebAPI using HttpContext.Current.Items but that doesn't exist in SignalR.

I know that ThreadStatic won't work because a SignalR thread can be shared between multiple requests.

For reference I am hosting it within IIS and using the latest version of SignalR (2.2.0)

Comment: Most solutions for this involve another, more persistent class or a dictionary in a pinch. Have you tried a `Dictionary<string, SomeCoolObject>`, mapping ConnectionIDs to whatever data you want to keep track of? Add people in `OnConnect`, remove them in `OnDisconnect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly very late for answering this question and maybe you have already figured out something for this. This is just an attempt to share my thought on this problem.

So to start with, you can enable authentication for SignalR, and then you can use `Context.User.xxx` in your hub methods.

For enabling [authentication for all hubs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization#requireauth) you can do something like this:

```
public partial class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.MapSignalR();
        GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
    }
}
```

Once you do that you can still use your usual authentication pipeline to authenticate your requests, and those information will be supplied to `Hub` methods via `Context.User` property. Below is one example from [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#add).

```
public async Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
{
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    Clients.Group(roomName).addChatMessage(Context.User.Identity.Name + " joined.");
}
```

Along with this you can maintain per-user data in an out-of-memory storage (so that it can scale out), such as Redis cache or something similar.

Or as an alternative approach, you can also extend [HubPipelineModule](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline), and create a [custom one](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline) to have more granular control on events.

```
public class LoggingPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule 
{ 
    protected override bool OnBeforeIncoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext context) 
    { 
        return base.OnBeforeIncoming(context); 
    }   
    protected override bool OnBeforeOutgoing(IHubOutgoingInvokerContext context) 
    { 
        return base.OnBeforeOutgoing(context); 
    } 
}

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) 
{ 
    GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new LoggingPipelineModule()); 
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Hope this helps. Also it would be interesting to know how you have dealt with the problem.